# how to compare a line to an empty line in bash?

Tags: bash

i have this function that i am using in a script , in this function i read from a file and in this file i have lines that are empty , now i want to use grep on this file , but i don't know what to do if grep didn't find the wanted sentence , which means i want to compare to an empty line :

what i tried: 
i went to the files in my current directory and in each file i read line by line in order to remove extra spaces then i used grep on the current line , and if "abcd" does not exist in the current line then move to the next one.

```
function print_lines {  
for file in *; do
   while read f ; do  
   local line=`echo "$f"`
   local x="`echo "$line" | grep -w "abcd"`"   
   if [[ "$x" != " " ]]; then                           
  echo "i found "$x""
 fi
 done < "$file"
 done 
 }
```

i know i am comparing $x to an empty line in a wrong way ! how can i do it corectly ?

also i can't use sed , awk ...

Comment: you're doing other things wrong as well.  what is it that you want to do?  Find "abcd" in files in a directory?

Comment: yes i just want to find this string

Comment: `grep -w newprogrammerha *`

Comment: i didn't get what you are trieng to do ..

Comment: `grep` can search all lines in a file and multiple files in one process, there is no reason to spoon feed lines to it.  Also if you're just interested in the status, you can run with `-q` and check the exit code.

Comment: ok thank you so much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[[ "$x" != " " ]]` doesn't compare with an empty line, it compares with a single *space.* What you would need is something akin to `[[ "$x" != "" ]]`.

However, `bash` has *specific* tests for comparing empty strings:

```
[[ -z "${x}" ]]
```

You can test this with:

```
pax> str="$(echo hello | grep e)" ; [[ -z "${str}" ]] && echo empty
pax> str="$(echo hello | grep z)" ; [[ -z "${str}" ]] && echo empty
empty
```

---

However, this is all moot since `bash` has the ability to search strings for simple things, *without* involving `grep` at all<sup>(a)</sup>:

```
pax> str=hello ; [[ ${str/e/} != ${str} ]] && echo has an e
has an e
pax> str=hello ; [[ ${str/z/} != ${str} ]] && echo has an z
```

The `${var/searchFor/replaceWith}` construct will modify the string if the search string was found (in our case, removing the matching text). So, if the modified string is *different* to the original, it means it contained what you were looking for.

---

<sup>(a)</sup> This is *especially* important when you're calling it a lot (as in within a line processing loop like here). Process start-up and tear-down is not free so, if you can avoid it, you'll find you can often get a performance boost.

Comment: so if i do  this it  means that grep didn't find "abcd" in the current line ?

Comment: @newprogrammerha: yes, see the update for how to test.

Answer (score 1):

what you need is just

```
$ if grep -wq "abcd" *; then echo "found"; fi
```

or

```
$ grep -wq "abcd" * && echo "found"
```